# Additional email onto following code

Tags: php, email, bespoke.js

How do I add an additional email onto the following:

```
$shop_email = $site->config->business_email;
```

I have already tried a lot of combinations (below), but they don't work:

```
$shop_email = $site->config->business_email, email@domain.com; 

$shop_email = array("$site->config->business_email","email@domain.com";
```

Thanks.

Comment: this is unclear; which framework/mailer are you using and how are emails being populated?

Comment: It's a bespoke platform, but I just need to amend that line of code so it also sends to a set email I put in manually. Thanks

Comment: If it's a bespoke platform, how are we supposed to know how the `$shop_email` variable is used?

Comment: ¢shop_email is taken from a database, but i'm not asking to edit the $shop_email, I'm asking to add an email to the existing line of code of:
$shop_email = $site->config->business_email;

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information in your question to provide an informed answer. However, assuming that `business_email` is an array, you can do something like this:

```
$shop_email = $site->config->business_email;
$shop_email[] = 'email@domain.com';
```

If `business_email` is not an array but a string, you can do this instead:

```
$shop_email = [$site->config->business_email,'email@domain.com'];
```

HTH..